# Why does $v=\sqrt{gR}$ guarantee circular motion -- why do we only consider the top point?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's assume we have a body undergoing vertical circular motion. The body is connected with a cord to a fixed point. The length of the cord is $ R $ (radius).

Why does a topmost speed of $v=\sqrt{gR}$ *guarantee* that the body will undergo circular motion.

Comment: I have voted this question down because a) it has changed so materially that it is no longer the same as the original, and b) the question is badly drafted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For there to be circular motion, the particle must have a speed at the top of $v=\sqrt{gR}$.

Note: I mixed up tension force for normal force, although this answer is equally valid for both.

Consider the following diagram of a particle of mass $m$ undergoing vertical circular motion.

[image]

Notice that for the motion to be circular, you must have that $$\dfrac{mv^2}R=mg\sin\theta + N$$ in the top quadrants.

The normal force will be "whatever it needs to be" such that the motion is circular, but, physically, it cannot be negative, so $N\geq0$. That is, if gravity is not strong enough to provide the necessary centripetal force to maintain circular motion, then the normal force will provide that extra necessary force.

Now, why would the particle break its circular trajectory? Because the force of gravity pulling towards the center would be too big. In other words, the motion would no longer be circular if $mg\sin\theta > \dfrac{mv^2}R$.

We know that *if* there is a normal force acting on the particle, then $mg\sin\theta<\dfrac{mv^2}R$, since the normal force is what makes $mg\sin\theta + N=\dfrac{mv^2}R$.

Therefore, if we want the motion to be circular at all points, we must have that $N\geq0$ at all points. Recall $$\dfrac{mv^2}R=mg\sin\theta + N.$$

So, we ask ourselves, where would $N=0$? We know that $N$ will decrease as we go to the topmost point, and be at a minimum at the topmost point.

Let's recap:

1. For vertical circular motion, $N$ must be $N\geq0$ at *all* points. If (mathematically), it is required for $N$ to be negative such that $\dfrac{mv^2}R=mg\sin\theta + N$ holds, then there will not be circular motion.
2. The minimal value of $N$ occurs at the top, where $mg\sin\theta=mg$ is maximized, and $mv^2/R$ is minimized.

Thus, if we can guarantee that $N\geq0$ at the top, then we can be sure there is circular motion. Now, to guarantee that, suppose $N=0$. If $N=0$, at the top, then $N\geq 0$ everywhere else, and so we have circular motion everywhere. Hence, at the top, we must have $\dfrac{mv^2}R= mg$ which gives us $v=\sqrt{gR}$, the minimal speed required at the top of the circle such that circular motion occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, at the top of the circular motion, we have

$$T+mg=\frac{mv^2}{R}$$

Where $T$ is the tension in the cord and $T+mg$ is the centripetal force.

When the velocity decreases the tension decreases but the force of gravity stays the same. Consequently, impending falling of the particle at the top of the circular motion occurs when the velocity decreases to the point where the tension becomes zero, and we have

$$mg=\frac{mv^2}{R}$$

and thus the minimum velocity to maintain circular motion is

$$v=\sqrt {gR}$$

Hope this helps.