# A falling particle on a "roller coaster"

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity

Suppose a particle is sliding down the hill only because of gravity. But then the hill smoothly flattens out and the particle has to pass a circular loop and must not fall off the loop at any instant and must not start going backwards. In the loop, the particle is in non-uniform circular motion and it has to complete one turn.

If the particle reaches just the *top point* of the loop and doesn't fall off at that point, <s>*then it always completes one full turn*</s>. Why is that?

An analogy with clocks (the loop is situated to the right of the hill): if the particle is in position **6**, then we say the particle is at the bottom of the loop. If the particle is in position **12**, then we say it is at the top of the loop, etc. If the particle ever reaches position **11** (i.e. it manages to get in the upper left quadrant of the loop), <s>then it *always* passes positions **10** and **9**.</s> This doesn't agree with my intuition at all... Of course, it won't fall off *after* reaching position **9**.

Don't assume friction, air resistance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretend that the roller coaster track stops at the top of the loop. The particle the leaves the track horizontally at a speed of $\sqrt{gr}$. If you plot the trajectory of the particle once it leaves the track, you will see that it would be completely outside the circle of the track loop. The plot below was created [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ajr08g6qhe).

[image: A plot of a circular looping track and the parabolic path of a particle that leaves the track at the top of the loop.]

The first equation $x^2 + (y-R)^2 = R^2$ defines the loop with radius $R$. The minimum velocity $v$ is calulcated from $R$ and the gravitational acceleration $g$. The parabolic path is the path the cart would take if it left the track at the top of the loop. If you zoom in, you will see that the parabolic trajectory is always above the loop.

This means that the track must put an inward force on the particle to constrain it to move on the loop. The fact that the track must put a force on the particle means the particle must be in contact with the track. If the particle has sufficient speed at the top of the loop, it cannot leave the track.

Answer (score 0):

> If the particle reaches just the top point of the loop and doesn't fall off at that point, then it always completes one full turn. Why is that?

No. The speed of the particle at the top must be $v=\sqrt{gr}$ where $r$ is the circle radius for it not to fall off. Here is a derivation of that equation: [Why does $v=\sqrt{gR}$ guarantee circular motion -- why do we only consider the top point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/635403/why-does-v-sqrtgr-guarantee-circular-motion-why-do-we-only-consider-the/635410#635410)

Comment: If I understand correctly, we are looking for the place with *minimal* tangential acceleration?

Comment: no, for the place with minimal velocity (the top), which is where the center-seeking gravity is strongest. if for the lowest speed and strongest center-seeking gravity the condition for circular motion is met, then it will be met for all other points where the object has a greater speed and weaker center-seeking gravity. by center-seeking gravity I mean the component of gravity that is directed towards the center of the circle @1mik1

Comment: At the top of the circle, it is the only place where both normal force and weight point in the same direction. This means that the tangential acceleration is zero at the top. But why is *velocity* minimal at the top?

Comment: I get it now. The velocity is minimal at the top because the kinetic energy is minimal at the top. But what do you mean by "component of gravity that is directed towards the center"? Of course, gravity changes with altitude, but in this problem it is assumed that $g$ is constant and is always pointing in the direction perpendicular to the ground.